# Moment of Inertia in the presence of strings

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I've seen that in some problems when strings are present, to get the required answer, it is considered as if the string was not present and the mass being directly attached to the pulley/other body. For example in this case(taken from IE Irodov's Problems in General Physics, $1.259$). The body A has a mass m and it had been asked to find the linear acceleration of A. The final answer comes out to be the same as if we were to assume A attached to the pulley directly, without any string. Its contribution to moment of inertia turns out to be $9m{R^2}$ (about centre of pulley). Why is it that the string can be ignored in such a case while computing the moment of inertia?

[image]

Also can this similar method be applied when the string isn't vertical but horizontal? For instance say I had a vertical rod of mass m and length L, a string attached horizontally to it at its centre which binds around a pulley and is attached to a hanging block of same mass m. Can I say that the effective moment of inertia(about O) would be $m{L^2}/3+m{L^2}/4$?The spring,pulley and string are massless in the figure below

[image]

Comment: it's an assumption to make exercises easier, without unnecessary complications.